# sharepoint 2010 quick launch missing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, quicklaunch

Recently our client complained quick launch is missing. The quick launch menu in sites is temperamental. sometimes it appears and works fine, other times it completely disappears. I checked the site settings, master page, Timer jobs everything is working fine. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem intermittently occurring on the same page, or does it consistently occur every time on the same pages?

Comment: It consistently occur on everytime on same site collection

Comment: If you edit one of the pages that is missing the left navigation can you change the page layout or is the option missing?

Comment: I changed the page layout, still it is not working

Comment: Only some page layouts have the quick launch. For example, in my farm the "Splash" layout doesn't have the quick launch however; the Blank Web Part Page does. Both are in the "Welcome Page" category of Page Layouts.

Answer (score 1):

If the Quick Launch menu is missing from specific pages then the problem is likely due to the page layout, which can be changed on Publishing Sites or site with the Publishing Feature enabled. To do so, edit the page and then select a new page layout from the Page tab of the ribbon. Here is an article with more information:

https://anujpant.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/sharepoint-2010-publishing-portal-missing-quick-launch/

If the left nav is missing from an entire site collection, it may be turned off. Use one of the following procedures to enable the quick launch:

To display the Quick Launch menu using the SharePoint 2010 web interface, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to Site Actions, Site Settings, Tree View (under Look and Feel).
2. Select the Enable Quick Launch check box and click OK

To display the Quick Launch menu using SharePoint Designer 2010, follow these steps:

1. Open the designer by clicking All Programs on the Start menu, selecting SharePoint, and clicking Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010.
2. In the Recent Sites section, select the site to which you want to add the Quick Launch menu. (If this is your first time opening SharePoint Designer, you won't see any sites listed in the Recent Sites section. In this case, click the Open Site button. In the Open Site dialog box, enter the URL to your SharePoint site and click Open.)
3. Once you’re in the site, click Home (under Site Objects) in the left navigation pane. In the Settings section, select the Display Quick Launch check box.
4. Click Save.

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/four-ways-add-or-remove-quick-launch-menu-control